# Creating a python comment string with only VIM commands

Tags: vim

I have a vim function:

```
function! Pycom(word)
    let a:inserted_word = ' ' . a:word . ' '
    let a:word_width = strlen(a:inserted_word)
    let a:length_before = (118 - a:word_width) / 2
    let a:hashes_before = repeat('#', a:length_before)
    let a:hashes_after = repeat('#', 118 - (a:word_width + a:length_before))
    let a:hash_line = repeat('#', 118)
    let a:word_line = '# '. a:hashes_before . a:inserted_word . a:hashes_after

    :put =toupper(a:word_line)
endfunction
```

```
noremap <leader>pc :call Pycom('')<Left><Left>
```

that creates Python comments. The output is like so:

`# ########################################### Hello World ############################################`

How can I create a key mapping to place in my vimrc to create my comment string with only Vim commands? I need to do this because I use PyCharm and in Vim emulation mode it does not allow calling functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If just `:function` were missing, you could inline the individual commands into a long, unsightly command sequence. But it's unlikely that a Vim emulation will just omit functions; the problem is that Vimscript itself is tightly bound to Vim itself, and mostly just specified by the behavior by its sole implementation inside Vim. So I'd guess that `strlen()`, `repeat()`, and even `:put ={expression}` won't work in PyCharm, neither.

Most Vim emulations just offer basic `:map` commands. Without knowning anything about PyCharm, the following general approaches can be tried:

- If the emulation offers the `:!` (or `:{range}!`) command to invoke external commands, you can implement the functionality in an external command, implemented in whatever programming language you prefer. (If the emulation doesn't offer the `:{range}!` command, you'd have to `:write` the buffer first and pass the filename and current location somehow to the external command.)
- Some emulations also offer a non-standard command to invoke their own core editor functions (so you might be able to implement it with that) or even arbitrary custom code; for example, for a NodeJS-based editor, that could be JavaScript code.

In general, Vim emulations are quite limited and can only emulate basic vi features (though I've also seen custom re-implementations of some popular Vim plugins, like surround.vim).

#### Alternative

To get more of Vim's special capabilities into your IDE, use *both* concurrently; it is very easy to set up a external tool in your IDE that launches Vim with the current file (and position). Automatic reloading of changes (in Vim via `:set autoread`) allows you to edit source code in both concurrently.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer.